# .env do not work with AVA

Tags: javascript, testing, filesystems, ava

I'm receiving the following error, when I try to run my tests using ava with my project that uses dotenv-safe

```
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: '.env' }
fs.js:549
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env.example'
```

it looks like ava is not finding .env or .env.example files

is there any workaround or a solution for this?

this is a repo that u can easily reproduce the issue: https://github.com/sibelius/koa-env-ava

Comment: Do you have a repo or minimal reproduction in a gist you can share?

Comment: yes, just added on questions, also here: https://github.com/sibelius/koa-env-ava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a quick look, here's a PR that gets things working: https://github.com/sibelius/koa-env-ava/pull/1

What was happening was that `dotenv-safe` did not know where to find your `.env` and `.env.example` files, so it would look in the `src` directory and throw an error. I rewrote your `src/config.js` file to automatically look in your project root directory:

```
const root = require('path').join.bind(this, __dirname, '..');

require('dotenv-safe').load({
  path: root('.env'),
  sample: root('.env.example')
});

export const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;
export const SERVER_PORT = process.env.SERVER_PORT;
```

This way `dotenv-safe` knows where to load your `.env` files from.